# Fetching JSON object Array from Local Server using Firefox -> CSP Error/NetworkError

Tags: javascript, json, api, firefox

Hope you guys are having a good night, I've just gone down a rabbit hole for 1 1/2 hours so apologise in advance for asking this question and taking yur time up.

So, I am trying to fetch the posts located at: http://localhost:5000/posts

When I use

```
fetch('/posts')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(resBody => console.log(resBody));
```

In the FireFox Developer Console I get:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:5000/posts ("default-src").

Promise { <state>: "rejected", <reason>: TypeError }
​
<state>: "rejected"
​
<reason>: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
​
<prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
```

Using Postman, I can retireve the array of JSON objects(The Posts)

`[{"postId":1,"message":"Hello World!"},{"postId":2,"message":"Ciao!"}]`

I can make POST requests and add new posts to the server using Postman.

The problem is when I try to do it in the developer console with FireFox.

I don't think it has anything to do with the server code(Since Postman works correctly, but here is the server code if you want to run it.)

````
const posts = [
  {
    postId: 1,
    message: "Hello World!"
  },
  {
    postId: 2,
    message: "Ciao!"
  },
];

let nextPostId = 3;

function getNewPostId() {
  const newPostId = nextPostId;
  nextPostId++;
  return newPostId;
}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let reqBody = "";
  req.on("data", (data) => {
    reqBody += data;
  });

  req.on("end", () => {
    // Parse the body of the request as JSON if Content-Type header is
      // application/json
    // Parse the body of the request as x-www-form-urlencoded if Content-Type
      // header is x-www-form-urlencoded
    if (reqBody) {
      try {
        const contentType = req.headers['content-type'];
        if (contentType === 'application/json') {
          req.body = JSON.parse(reqBody);
        } else if (contentType === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
        req.body = reqBody
          .split("&")
          .map((keyValuePair) => keyValuePair.split("="))
          .map(([key, value]) => [key, value.replace(/\+/g, " ")])
          .map(([key, value]) => [key, decodeURIComponent(value)])
          .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
            acc[key] = value;
            return acc;
          }, {});
        }
      } catch (e) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.write(JSON.stringify("Could not parse body"));
        return res.end();
      }
    }

    if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/posts') {
      // Return the posts array as JSON in the body of the response
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.write(JSON.stringify(posts));
      return res.end();
    }

    if (req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/posts') {
      // Return the posts array as JSON in the body of the response
      const { message } = req.body;
      if (!message) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.write(JSON.stringify("Message is required"));
        return res.end();
      }
      const post = { postId: getNewPostId(), message };
      posts.push(post);
      res.statusCode = 201;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.write(JSON.stringify(post));
      return res.end();
    }

    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.write(JSON.stringify("Endpoint not found"));
    return res.end();
  });
});

const port = 5000;

server.listen(port, () => console.log('Server is listening on port', port));```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a CORs policy error with Firefox and Chrome will actually work perfectly fine.

The solution I used was to use Chrome when using local APIs.